# How do I replace a segment in a command in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

So I'm creating a small script that allows to directly access a stream. I'm having problems in `twitch.tv/%stream[%%i]%`, where I want to replace `%stream[%%i]%` with the streamers username from the array "stream".

```
@echo off
echo Streamer list:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set stream[0]=dakotaz
set stream[1]=kingrichard
set stream[2]=ninja
set stream[3]=tsm_myth
set /a i=1
for /l %%n in (0,1,3) do (
    echo !i!. !stream[%%n]!
    set /a i=i+1
)
set /p i=Which streamer would you like to watch?
set /a i=i-1
livestreamer --twitch-oauth-token xxxxxxx twitch.tv/%stream[%%i]% best
```

I'm not sure if it's even possible, I never used batch before.

Comment: The variable `i` is an environmental variable so it will normally be referenced with surrounding percent symbols: `%i%`.  You also need to reference the stream variable with delayed expansion. So your variable would be reference like this: `!stream[%i%]!`

Answer (score 0):

As Squashman already noted, the correct way to address the variable is `!stream[%i%]!`.

I suggest a little change to make it more straigtforward (there is no need to start counting with zero):

```
@echo off
echo Streamer list:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set stream[1]=dakotaz
set stream[2]=kingrichard
set stream[3]=ninja
set stream[4]=tsm_myth
for /l %%n in (1,1,4) do (
    echo !i!. !stream[%%n]!
)
set /p i=Which streamer would you like to watch?
livestreamer --twitch-oauth-token xxxxxxx twitch.tv/!stream[%i%]! best
```